# How to add an item to database directly in django without forms

Tags: python, django, database

I know, this question has already been discussed, but I am unable to grab that.

Here are two models I have

```
# Create your models here.
GENDER_CHOICES = [
    ('Male', 'M'),
    ('Female', 'F')]
class upload(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    email=  models.EmailField(max_length=50,null=True)
    file=models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/',null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class text(models.Model):
    texts=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    upload_text=models.ForeignKey(upload, blank=True, null=True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

I have a form for model `upload`. I inserted the data, and an audio file. Then I want this audio file to convert to text and save the text in the database.
For that purpose, I created another model `text`.

But I don't know how to insert the text to this model in relation to the information entered in model `upload`

Here is my views.py file function

```
def display(request):
    print('display functio')
    d=upload.objects.last()
    test=sr.takeCommand(d.file.path)
    print(test) **# I can see text here**
    p = text.objects.create(texts=test)
    p.save(force_insert=True)
    print(test)
    return render(request,'thanks.html',{'print':test})
```

But I am unable to enter it. It throws an error
`UNIQUE constraint failed: sub_app_text.id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you insert it *twice*. The [**`.create(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#create) already *inserts* in in the database. So you can implement this as:

```
def display(request):
    print('display functio')
    d=upload.objects.last()
    test=sr.takeCommand(d.file.path)
    # will store the record in the database
    p = text.objects.create(texts=test)
    print(test)
    return render(request,'thanks.html',{'print':test})
```

you can link it to `d` with:

```
def display(request):
    print('display functio')
    d=upload.objects.last()
    test=sr.takeCommand(d.file.path)
    # will store the record in the database
    p = text.objects.create(texts=test, upload_text=d)
    print(test)
    return render(request,'thanks.html',{'print':test})
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PerlCase*, not
> *snake_case*, so you might want to rename the model from <s>`text`</s> to `Text`.

Comment: ok, this works. but its not assigned to the user of `upload` method

Comment: @TalhaAnwar: but where do you link the `Text` object to a user? You only have a `ForeignKey` to the `upload` model, but you never construct an `upload` object. Nor has your `upload` model a link to a user such that we can link it to the `upload` of the logged in user. Unless `upload` is a *custom user model* (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) that will be quite painful.

Comment: oops. sorry, i missed the parameter `upload_text=d`. Adding this connect both tables. Thanks